# How to highlight the first word in every sentence in a string?

Tags: javascript, string, loops

We have an assignment where we have to highlight the first word in every sentence. For example if we have the string "I love apples. You love oranges. We love fruit." we have to highlight "I", "You", "We" - the first word after a period.

Can anyone help?

Comment: What do you mean by highlight ?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. If you have written code for this that you can't get to work, then you have come to the right place. Just **[edit]** the question and add the relevant parts of your code into it. You need to show your own efforts, because Stack Overflow is not a write-my-code-for-me service. Also please see **[ask]**.

Comment: What do you mean by highlighting? Did you try anything yourself ?

Comment: Are you rendering the text with html and css ?

Comment: Please provide code of what have you tried so far

Answer (score 1):

```
var words = "I love apples.You love oranges.We love fruit";
var words_array = words.split(".");
var first_words = [];
$(words_array).each(function(k,word){
    first_words.push(word.split(" ")[0]);
});
```

**Result**
first_words;
(3) ["I", "You", "We"]

Answer (score 0):

Just split your text by '.' to get all sentences.
Then split again by white-space to find the first word of each sentence to highlight.

```js
let text = "I love apples. You love oranges. We love fruit.";
let sentences = text.split('.');

for(let i in sentences) {
 let sentence = sentences[i].trim();
  
  if(sentence){
   let firstWhiteSpace = sentence.indexOf(' ');
   sentence = '*' + sentence.substring(0, firstWhiteSpace) + '*' + sentence.substring(firstWhiteSpace) + '.';
   console.log(sentence);
  }
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/eu81273/jsfiddle-console/master/console.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope that helps!

```
const texts = 'I love you. You love me. hello world';
let newText = '';

texts.split('.').forEach(text => {
  const edit = text.trim().split(' ');
  newText +=  `<mark>${edit.shift()}</mark> ${edit.join(' ')}. `;
});
document.body.innerHTML = newText.trim();
```

Answer (score 0):

With Regex you write less of code.

```
let texts = 'I love you. You love me. hello world.';
texts = texts.replace(/(^|\.\s)([a-z]+)/gi, "$1 <mark>$2</mark>");
document.body.innerHTML = texts;
```